# Is it possible to set image for the "over scrolled" (bounced) area of a web page (for mobile)?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

Most mobile browser will have a default behavior to allow the users to continue scrolling when they reach the top or bottom of a page, leaving a white space on the top or bottom of the page. And then the whole page will bounce back to fill the white space. In native iOS applications, we can easily set images and even interactive elements for these top and bottom areas. I wonder if this can be done for pure web applications.

What I tried is to set background image of `html,body`, for example:

```
html, body {
  background: url(../img/topnotification.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Unfortunately this didn't work because it seems the enter body was being over scrolled. I wonder if there is a special property we can set for the top and bottom empty over scroll areas for mobile websites.

I also have tried:

```
html:before, body:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../img/topnotification.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

This apparently didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this depends solely on the browser as I do not know of any html elements that specify white spaces resulting from over scrolling. 
Personally I never experienced any thing like this in windows, chrome, and android.
You might be able to create an animation that happens when the scrolling reaches the bottom or the footer of the page, but I do not think anything can be done to fill in the white space. It is mostly likely browser based.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but rather a comment. However I understand since you do not have enough rep yet to post comments. I would suggest to try answering some easy questions to gain 50 rep at least. Otherwhise, adding some links to documentation or alternative methods can make your answer more answer-like.

Comment: sorry, thanks for your advice. people recommended stack overflow as the question asking site for developers so i tried this yesterday.